# How to use GNU find command to find files by pattern and list files in order of most recent modification to least?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gnu, gnu-findutils

I want to use the GNU `find` command to find files based on a pattern, and then have them displayed in order of the most recently modified file to the least recently modified.

**I understand this:**

`find / -type f -name '*.md'`

but then what would be added to sort the files from the most recently modified to the least?

---

Answer (score 2):

`find` can't sort files, so you can instead output the modification time plus filename, sort on modification time, then remove the modification time again:

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -printf '%T@ %p\0' |   # Print time+name
  sort -rnz |                                      # Sort numerically, descending
  cut -z -d ' ' -f 2- |                            # Remove time
  tr '\0' '\n'                                     # Optional: make human readable
```

This uses `\0`-separated entries to avoid problems with any kind of filenames. You can pass this directly and safely to a number of tools, but here it instead pipes to `tr` to show the file list as individual lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
find <dir> -name "*.mz" -printf "%Ts - %h/%f\n" | sort -rn
```

Print the modified time in epoch format (%Ts) as well as the directories (%h) and file name (%f). Pipe this through to sort -rn to sort in reversed number order.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of `find` to `xargs` and `ls`:

```
find / -type f -name '*.md' | xargs ls -1t
```

Comment: I'd recommend `find ... -exec ls 1t {} +` over `xargs`. `-exec +` is not only faster, but also avoids a lot of quoting issues.